# Drop down list menu programmatically in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, drop-down-menu

I have made a drop down `gender` which is working fine however I have another drop down on same `viewcontroller` which shows drop down but when I select the item it gives error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` I have tried out but confused. help me to solve the `bloodList` dropdown.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var genderButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func genderButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.PressDrop()
    view.addSubview(genderTable)
}
@IBOutlet weak var genderTable: UITableView!

var flag = 1
var dropDownList = [String]()
@IBOutlet weak var bloodButton: UIButton!
var bloodList = [String]()
@IBAction func bloodButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.PressBlood()
    view.addSubview(bloodTable)
}
@IBOutlet weak var bloodTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dropDownList = ["Male", "Female", "Other"]
    genderTable.delegate = self
    genderTable.dataSource = self
    genderTable.isHidden = true
    view.addSubview(genderTable) 
    genderTable.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    bloodList = ["A+", "A-", "AB+", "AB-"] 
    bloodTable.delegate = self
    bloodTable.dataSource = self
    bloodTable.isHidden = true
    view.addSubview(bloodTable)
    bloodTable.layer.cornerRadius = 10  
}

func PressDrop() {
    if flag == 0 {
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        self.genderTable.isHidden = true
        self.flag = 1
    }
    else{
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        self.genderTable.isHidden = false
        self.flag = 0
    }
}

func PressBlood() {
    if flag == 0 {
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        self.bloodTable.isHidden = true
        self.flag = 1
    }
    else{
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        self.bloodTable.isHidden = false
        self.flag = 0
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dropDownList.count

}

func tableViewBlood(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return bloodList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = genderTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = dropDownList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableViewTwo(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = bloodTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bloodCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = bloodList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let   selectedData = dropDownList[indexPath.row]
    genderButton.setTitle(selectedData, for: .normal)
    self.genderTable.isHidden = true
    self.flag = 
    let indexPath = genderTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = genderTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
    let finalresult = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
    print("\(finalresult)")
}

private func tableViewTwo(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let   selectedBlood = bloodList[indexPath.row]
    bloodButton.setTitle(selectedBlood, for: .normal)
    self.bloodTable.isHidden = true
    self.flag = 1
    let indexPathTwo = bloodTable.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCellBlood = bloodTable.cellForRow(at: indexPathTwo!)! as UITableViewCell
    let finalresultBlood = currentCellBlood.textLabel!.text!
    print("\(finalresultBlood)")
}
}
```

Comment: Set breakpoints and try to pinpoint where the nullability error is. Just regurgitating all of your code is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited for an answer but did not find :( that's ok . I thought a number of times and then come to this code yahoooo!!! then i believed i am really a programmer. Actually i did not defined the condition for each table view so i was in nightmare. This code is pure programatically and **does not require** any irritating third **party library** or awkward **pods**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == tableViewB {
    return dropDownList.count
    }
    else {
    return genderL.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == tableViewB { 
    let cell = tableViewB.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = dropDownList[indexPath.row]
    return cell     
    }  
    else {
        let cell = genderT.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "gender", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = genderL[indexPath.row]
        return cell  
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView == tableViewB {
    let   selectedData = dropDownList[indexPath.row]
    buttonB.setTitle(selectedData, for: .normal)
    self.tableViewB.isHidden = true
    self.flag = 1
    let indexPath = tableViewB.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let currentCell = tableViewB.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
    let finalresult = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
    print("\(finalresult)")
    }
    else {
        let   selectedDataG = genderL[indexPath.row]
        genderB.setTitle(selectedDataG, for: .normal)
        self.genderT.isHidden = true
        self.flag = 1
        let indexPath = genderT.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = genderT.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
        let finalresult = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
        print("\(finalresult)")
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change default delegate methods of your tableView, give conditions in the delegate methods like below :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      if tableView == genderTable {
          return dropDownList.count
      }
      return bloodList.count
    }
```

Also make similar changes in the remaining delegate methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == genderTable {
        let cell = genderTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = dropDownList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
} else {
        let cell = bloodTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bloodCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = bloodList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if tableView == genderTable { 
        let   selectedData = dropDownList[indexPath.row]
        genderButton.setTitle(selectedData, for: .normal)
        self.genderTable.isHidden = true 
        let currentCell = genderTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        let finalresult = currentCell.textLabel!.text!
        print("\(finalresult)")
     } else {
        let   selectedBlood = bloodList[indexPath.row]
        bloodButton.setTitle(selectedBlood, for: .normal)
        self.bloodTable.isHidden = true
        let currentCellBlood = bloodTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
        let finalresultBlood = currentCellBlood.textLabel!.text!
        print("\(finalresultBlood)")
   }
}
```

Comment: `let indexPath = genderTable.indexPathForSelectedRow` gives error `expected expression`

Comment: What do you want when you select the cell ?

Comment: i want the value get printed in console

Comment: What value you want to print ? What is the textLabel ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141628/discussion-between-sneha-and-xcodian).

Answer (score 1):

Don't create like this

```
func tableViewTwo(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell (This will consider as new method to your current class)
```

They are all in build **delegate** methods of **UITableview**, you should override it, you cannot change it.

Instead of creating method, you try with **Bool** variable in respective button action.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

If isDrop == true{
    return dropDownList.count
}else{
return bloodList.count
}

}
```

Like change the condition

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```